# An algorithm for edge detection without color losing

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm looking for the algorithm (C#) or some info about how detect the edge of some object on the image (the target is the melanoma). I've found the `AForge.NET` library but I need to detect an `edge without losing the image color`. The examples below were prepared using the `Paint.NET`

Before:

[image]

after

[image]

I need only that blue edge (the color inside doesn't matter) or the that blue pixels coordinates

### EDIT

[Matthew Chambers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773494/106616) was right, converting the image to the grayscale improves the effectiveness of the algorithm.
The first result image is based on the original coloured image, and the second one is based on the grayscaled image. The blue pixels corresponds to the HSV's Value < 30. You can see the differences by yourself. Thanks m8 !

[image]

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ?

Comment: I have tested popular methods of the edge detecting but all of them make the image gray-scaled and also hard to read what were on the image before processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider a few points related to the problem you are trying to solve.

What is an edge in a picture? Generally it is when the colour changes at a high rate. I.e. from dark to light in a short space.

But this has an issue about what a high rate of change for a colour actually is. For example, the Red and Green values could stay the same, while the Blue value changes at a high rate. Would we count this as an edge? This could occur for any combination of the RGB values.

For this reason, images are typically converted to greyscale for edge detection - otherwise you could get different edge results for each RGB value.

For this reason, the simplest approach would be to use a typical edge detection algorithm that works on a greyscale image, and then overlay the result onto the original image.

Comment: I thouth about the same method as You mentioned here. I've noticed that the HSV will be helpful here, especially the V - light colors has that value higher, and the dark colors - lower. I'll try to develop an algorithm which'll be using the HSV

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [`Edges`](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/84de24c4-699d-6469-4948-c617c9338554.htm) class:

```
// create filter
Edges filter = new Edges();
// apply the filter
var newImage = filter.Apply(orignalImage);
```

Then do a [threshold](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/503a43b9-d98b-a19f-b74e-44767916ad65.htm) on newImages, finally overlay `newImage` on top of `originalImage`.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to Lab color space, split channels, run edge detection code (like the one provided in other answer) on L channel only, then add back a and b channels.

Comment: can You provide me some more details ? I can't find useful informations or examples about what You're talking about

Comment: Check book image processing coockbook by John c Russ, he discusses this and similar techniques. He also has a webpage with tutorials so you may find some material there. http://drjohnruss.com/download.html
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/02/04/more-on-segmenting-in-a-b-space/

Comment: sorry, I was writing from mobile and hit Add comment by mistake and then was unable to edit on time. I meant to add to also check these two blog posts:http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/02/04/more-on-segmenting-in-a-b-space/ and http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/10/08/the-two-amigos/

Answer (score 1):

Considering the images and the question, it does not look like you need edge detection.
I would use an adaptive threshold technique instead, find the blob and finally extract the edge from it.

Here is a code in Matlab to illustrate what I mean:

```
function FindThresh()
    i = imread('c:\b.png');
    figure;imshow(i);
    graythresh(i)
    th = graythresh(i(:,:,2))*255;
    figure;imshow(i(:,:,2)>th)
    i1 = imclose(i(:,:,2)>th,strel('diamond',3));
    figure;imshow(i1)
    e = edge(i1);
    indexes = find(e);
    [r,c]=ind2sub(size(i1),indexes)

    figure;imshow(e)
    figure;imshow(i);hold on; scatter(c,r);
end
```

and the intermediate results images:

[image: The figures]

You can see that it is not perfect, but by improving it a little bit, you will get more powerful results than by using edge detection which is not a stable operation.